# Duvida sobre função JS

Tags: javascript, funções

Tenho a função myFunction que calcula o produto de dois numeros e exibe eles na tela. Gostaria de desviar esta função para a função listen quando o valor de p1=10. Do jeito que está, ele só exibe o valor de myFunction, e ignora a igualdade p1=10 para fazer o desvio. Podem me ajudar?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Functions</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(p1, p2) {

if (p1=10)  {listen(a)}
    return p1 * p2;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(10, 3);


var a ="jj";

function listen(k){
 var s1 = k;
 alert(s1);
 return k
 }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dei uma resposta ao problema principal do teu código, porem fico intrigado com a função `listen`. Qual é o seu papel? só fazer um `alert`? porquê o `return`? será para integrar no resultado de `myFunction`?

Answer (score 1):

> No seu código, além de estar fazendo uma atribuição aqui:

```
if (p1=10) // deveria ser if (p1==10)
```

> Você está definindo `a` depois de chamar a função:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(10, 3); 
var a ="jj";
```

> Por isso `a` é `undefined` - Mova `var a="jj";` para antes da função:

```
var a ="jj";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(10, 3);
```

> E acredito que o programa já irá funcionar como você quer. Mudei um pouquinho o seu código a seguir, só para ficar mais fácil testar, clique em **Executar** logo abaixo do código:

```js
function myFunction(p1, p2) {
    if (p1==10)  {listen(a)}
    else alert(p1 * p2);
}

function listen(k){
    var s1 = k;
    alert(s1);
    return k
}

var a ="jj";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Functions</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="number" id="valor1" value=10>
<input type="number" id="valor2" value=3>
<button onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('valor1').value,
  document.getElementById('valor2').value)">Testar Função</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: agora deu certo , era bem isto que precisava, grata

Comment: @Silezia por favor marque uma das respostas como aceita, clicando na marca que fica a esquerda do texto! :)

Answer (score 0):

Quando usas somente `=` em JavaScript isso é atribuição e não comparação.

Ou seja, o que `p1=10` faz é que `p1` passa a valer `10`.

Deves usar `==` para comparar o valor, ou `===` para comparar o valor e que seja do mesmo tipo.

Sugestão:

```js
var a = "jj";

function myFunction(p1, p2) {
  if (p1 == 10) return listen(a);
  else return p1 * p2;
}

function listen(k) {
  return k
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(10, 3);
```

```html
<h2>JavaScript Functions</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: a função listen, pode ser qualquer uma, por exemplo "valor",

Comment: a função listen, pode ser qualquer uma, por exemplo "valor", O que eu desejo é desviar para a segunda função, quando houver comparação. Fiz o que voce disse, coloquei ==  e tambem === mas dá o valor undefined e a multiplicação P1*P2. Com numeros numeros , ao invez de escrever "a" na função, funciona. Porque não funciona com letras, Queria que a resposta quando fosse comparação, fosse "JJ" entendeu

Comment: @Silezia ainda não está muito claro para mim o que procuras. Dá uma olhada à sugestão que coloquei agora na resposta. É isso que procuras?

Comment: @Silezia ainda não está muito claro para mim o que procuras. Dá uma olhada à sugestão que coloquei agora na resposta. É isso que procuras?